# I have a table stored into memory. How do I sort it based on a column?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a table stored in **contiguous** memory. It needs to stay in that format after the sort.

For example:

```
int table[5][3] = {
    { 60, 5, 10 },
    { 0, 200, 15 },
    { 55, 50, 365 },
    { 4, 7, 78 },
    { 555, 8, 11 },
};
```

Except much bigger (the size of the biggest, in bytes, is approximately 27 KB). Each cell is always an int32, and all rows have the same amounts of columns.

Let's say that I want to sort it based on the first column, so that the result must be equivalent to:

```
    { 0, 200, 15 },
    { 4, 7, 78 },
    { 55, 50, 365 },
    { 60, 5, 10 },
    { 555, 8, 11 },
```

What's the best way to do this? I imagine there is a better way than to convert this to a `std::list`, call `sort()`, and convert back.

Also, something built into C++ where I just have to call some function would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::sort` won't do it easily because arrays aren't assignable.

However, `std::qsort` will do it:

```
int cmp_first_column(const void *lhs_, const void *rhs_) {
    // optimize this to taste
    const int *lhs = static_cast<const int*>(lhs_);
    const int *rhs = static_cast<const int*>(rhs_);
    if (lhs[0] < rhs[0]) return -1;
    if (lhs[0] > rhs[0]) return 1;
    return 0;
}

std::qsort(table, 5, 3*sizeof(int), cmp_first_colum);
```

OK, so `std::qsort` doesn't benefit from template inlining optimization, but it gets the job done and at least you aren't allocating a lot of memory and doing unnecessary copying.

You could instead look to replace your array of `int[3]` with an array of structs with an `int[3]` as a data member. That would then be assignable and you could use `std::sort` normally. Depends how much other code you have written that relies on the current type, and whether it's OK to break the interface that code uses.

Comment: be careful: placing the array inside a struct could raise alignment issues and the array wouldn't end-up contiguous in memory as the OP asked for. I mean in this particular case it would probably work, but I won't apply this tric on array or chars.

Comment: @kriss: that's sort of why I say it has to be OK to break the interface that current code uses - I'm suggesting a change to the definition of the data structure involved, if that's possible. Personally I would *not* attempt to just type-pun an array of the struct over the top of the array of arrays, even if they just so happen to have the same layout on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- sorting with such large items tends to be slow simply because copying large items is slow.

You can (probably) speed it up by creating an index that contains the key (the item from the first column that you're using to do the sorting) and a pointer or index to the original row of data. Sort the index, then use that to copy the data into a new array in sorted order (and, if necessary, back to the original). This helps reduce the copying to a minimum, which can save a fair amount of time if your have a lot of columns.

OTOH, given that you're only talking about tens of kilobytes (or so) of data, you could pretty easily get by with just using `qsort` directly on the table (with a suitable comparison function). This is one of those rare situations where it may actually make sense to use `qsort` in C++. Since Steve Jessop has corrected his answer showing this method, I'll leave this to him rather than showing it here.

Comment: As with my (now-deleted) answer, this won't actually compile.  The `sort` algorithm will try to do assignments, which aren't legal on array types.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Yup -- I believe I've fixed that.

Comment: `INT_MAX - (-1)` is probably negative, but `INT_MAX` is greater than `-1`.

Comment: Corner cases? 50% of possible inputs, mutter grumble. Of course it's fine if the values are restricted in range to +/- INT_MAX/2.

Comment: 50% of possible inputs? Methinks you exaggerate just a tad. The problem only arises from specific combinations of values. Even with the (grossly unrealistic) assumption of values randomly distributed throughout the range of integers, the problem arises much less than half the time. That's not to say the code is great (that's why I've deleted it), but it doesn't have problems *nearly* as often as you imply either.

Comment: @Jerry: well, it's late at night, I thought that subtraction gives the wrong answer if and only if it overflows, hence half of possible inputs, if not half the time for realistic data. I confess I could be wrong. Not really important what the proportion is, I'm sure everyone's grown up enough to decide for themselves whether they can safely subtract two numbers :-)

Comment: No, not half of possible inputs. I believe it really works out to 25%. If both inputs are between -INT_MAX/2 and INT_MAX/2, then there's no overflow. That's half of possible inputs right there. If both are the same sign, it can't overflow either. To overflow, you need opposite signs *and* at least one with magnitude > INT_MAX/2.

Comment: "That's half of possible inputs right there" - that's *quarter* of all possible inputs right there. Half on the LHS crossed with half on the RHS.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I would write a simple sort, like bubble sort to do it for me rather than converting, using sort , converting back.

For bubble sort you just loop through the table looking at the data in a row and the row ahead of it,  then switch them if a > b etc, rinse and repeat till your data is sorted.  Its not the most efficient but its simple and fast over small sets of data.

Comment: I think this would be worse for large ammounts of data

Comment: Hmm...going to extra work to make the code less efficient doesn't strike me as the best use of time.

Comment: I wasn't recommending this for a huge amount of data but this method of sorting takes about 5 minutes to implement, as a quick easy solution a bubble sort works fine over small sets of data.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish: Selection sort is even *easier* to implement than bubble sort, and especially under the circumstances it's likely to be quite a bit faster to boot. The code to use `qsort` is easier and faster still.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish: 5 `programmers minutes` have a tendency to turn out as 5 hours including debug even for simple well known problems. Check by yourself, my raw guess is that implementing the simple BS will take no less than half an hour :-)

Comment: @purplegoldfish: OK, so going to *a little bit* of extra effort to make the code *a little bit* less efficient (for reasonably small inputs without too many tortoises), isn't the *worst* use of time. It's not the best either ;-)